# Wordpress image and link in header

Tags: image, wordpress, hyperlink, header, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress child theme of TwentyTwelve with a header image and I would like to place another smaller image with a hyperlink centered in the header image.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1                                                                 |
|                            -----    -----                         |
|                            | 2 |    | 3 |                         |
|                            -----    -----                         |
|                                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the diagram above, I have [1] being the link to the main site (standard from twentytwelve) and I would like to add [2] and [3] as images and hyperlinks. Any suggestions on how I would to this? I'm just starting to learn theming. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution if anyone else is looking to do this. In my `header.php`, I added this just before `</header>`:

```
<div style="position:relative; visibility:show; left: 50%; top: -<?php echo get_custom_header()->height/2; ?>px; z-index:2; >
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="image" ></a><br>
</div>
```